# Java List.remove not working with List<? extends AppData>

Tags: java

I'm working on a project and i'm stuck on why my object won't remove from the list.

```
List<? extends AppData> allData = adm.findAll(AdSortOrder.KeyAsc);
AppData data = adm.find(key);
System.out.println("allData before = "+allData.size()); // 988
allData.remove(data);  // DOES NOT ACTUALLY REMOVE
System.out.println("allData after = "+allData.size()); // 988. Shouldn't it be 987 now?
```

Comment: Are `equals()` and `hashCode()` implemented for `AppData`?

Comment: What do `AppData.equals`, `.findAll` and `.find()` methods look like?

Comment: @Keppil: That may well be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Most likely, data = adm.find(key) is returning null in the first place.

Comment: data is not returning null. AppData is an interface.

Comment: findAll returns `List<? extends AppData>` and find returns `AppData`

Comment: Then check equals() & hashCode() of AppData as Keppil asked

Answer (score 2):

As @Keppil suggests, the problem is likely in the `equals` implementation of the class implementing `AppData` you're using.

From the [`List#remove` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-):

> ...removes the element with the lowest index `i` such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))` (if such an element exists).

So if the item is not getting removed, that tells us that that condition is not being met, which suggests that `equals` is not correctly implemented for the class you're using that implements `AppData` (as you've said `AppData` is an interface).